# Appcelerator Dynamic TableViewRow title only appears after scroll

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am developing an App and I have a tableview that load data from an API, and render the tableviewrows from an external file.
When the screen opens, the tableview is blank, but If I scroll up the tableview, I can see the title in the firts rows.

Can you help me?  Thanks!

categorias.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">      
        <View class="titleBar">
            <Button id="backButton" onClick="backWindow" />
            <Label class="lblTitle">Categorias</Label>
            <Button id="nextButton" onClick="create" TipoAtributoId="0">Novo</Button>
        </View>
        <TableView id="tblData" top="70" editable="true" deleteButtonTitle="Apagar">
        </TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

categoria.js

```
function getCategoria(){    
    var rows = [];
    net.categoriaGet(function(data){
        $.tblData.data = [];
        if (data != null){
            for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                var arg = {
                    type:'categoria',
                    title: data[i].Nome,
                    id: data[i].CategoriaId
                };
                rows.push(Alloy.createController('row', arg).getView());
            }           
            $.tblData.setData(rows);
            Alloy.Globals.hideIndicator();
            rc.endRefreshing();
        } else {
            Alloy.Globals.hideIndicator();
            rc.endRefreshing();
        }

    });
}
```

row.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <TableViewRow id="rowView" onClick="edit"/>
</Alloy>
```

row.js

```
var args = $.args;
$.rowView.title = $.args.title;
```

[initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIDtZ.png)[screen after scroll to up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt7mf.png)

Comment: sounds like you have many empty rows if you need to scroll up..

Comment: No. When I scroll to up and the tableview scroll to bottom the title appears.
For example, If I have 5 rows and scroll only 2 rows to the top, only 2 titles appears, If I scroll the 5 rows than I can see the 5 titles.
Very crazy.

Comment: I have recorded the screen.  https://youtu.be/6KjwbyP1gAk